# Form onsumbit executing a function

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have this code:

```
function src(){
  var id = document.getElementsByName("query")[0].value;
  window.location.href = "/search/?query=" + id;
}
var f_src = document.getElementById("search_form");
if(f_src)
  f_src.onsubmit = function(){src();return false;};
```

I'm having problems with the submit part: I want, when I enter **"example"** in the field **"url"** to be redirected to **"/search/?query=example"**, but it's not working, any help?

HTML:

```
  <form id="search_form" method="get" action="" name="search_f">
    <input id="search_field" maxlength="100" name="query" type="text" value="" placeholder="<?php echo $src_txt; ?>">
    <input id="search_button" type="submit" value="">
  </form>
```

Thanks.

Comment: And the `<input />` field really has the `name` "url"? Please post your HTML as well and show where/when you execute the code. Do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: Remove return false; from the end, it will prohabit form from submitting.

Comment: @Felix Kling, my HTML is clean the input is "url", and I have no errors

Comment: @ParkashKumar The form is being submitted, I don't want it, I want to stop submitting and execute my function.

Comment: We cannot really help you if you don't provide more information. Aside from that, you can achieve what you are trying to do without JavaScript. You just have to set up your form properly. Is there any specific reason why you want to use JS for that?

Comment: Your function is being called, while your form is getting submitted. I think you are appending URL incorrectly.

Change it to: window.location.href += "/search/?query=" + id;

Comment: The input field in your HTML has the name `query`, not `url`.

Comment: What does your JS console say?

Comment: @FelixKling I'm in a random page of my site "http:123.456.com/page/page/my" I search and on submit I want to go to "http:123.456.com/search/?query=searchedString"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aside from the problem you might have, you can achieve the same behavior without JavaScript. You just have to give the form element the name "query" and make it submit a GET request to `/search`:

```
<form id="search_form" method="get" action="/search/" name="search_f">
    <input id="search_field" maxlength="100" name="query" type="text" value="" placeholder="<?php echo $src_txt; ?>">
    <input id="search_button" type="submit" value="">
</form>
```

The `action` attribute tells the browser where to make the request to. Every form control element with a `name` will be included with its value in the query string.

No JavaScript required.

Comment: Oh, man thank you this is what I was looking for, I'm not a so good programmer so sorry for my mistakes, just thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If You don't insist on using javascript, You can achieve this using good old HTML:

```
<form action="/search/" method="get">
    <input name="query" />
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks! I am browsing on cell-phone right now, which is a lot of pain :-)

Comment: Oh yeah, I can relate. I wouldn't even answer questions from a cell phone ;)